# Highchart Line only 1 data / name

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts, line

i want create highchart Line
wit my data, but i have a problem, because i'm only have 1 data / name
this result Highchart Line

[image]

i want data like this
[image]

but i'm only have 1 data / name, can you give me a solution

**this is my code**

```
 <div id="container_pie" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto">
    </div>
            <script> 
            //line
        $('#container_pie').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            credits:{enabled: false},
            exporting:{enabled: true},
            title: {
                text: 'List GDP'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
               categories: ['']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    enableMouseTracking: false
                }
            },
            series: [
        <?php 
        $sql_view = mysqli_fetch_object(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT query  from sql_view"));
        $data_test1 = mysqli_query($mydb,$sql_view->query); 
        while($get_data = mysqli_fetch_object($data_test1)) 
        { ?>
             {
                'name': '<?php echo $get_data->$data_name; ?>',
                'data': [<?php echo $get_data->$data_value; ?>]
             }, 
        <?php 
        }
        ?>

                ]
        });
            </script>
```

Comment: Well, you have to have multiple values on the x-axis to have a graph similar to what you expect.

Comment: @MasterDJon can you have a sample ?

Comment: You have to create multiple points within the series - instead you create multiples series with 1 point. See the difference [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vpt33xh3/)